# Laptop shutting down

Tags: windows, laptop, shutdown

I´ve been having random laptop shutdown issues in the last few months, which i cannot fix.
Thinking it could be a overheating issue, i proceeded to open the laptop and clean the vent and the fan, which turned out to be just a little dirty.
Then again, it keeps shutting down and im not sure how to diagnose this.

What should i do? any pointers/guidance on how to proceed?
Laptop is an Acer 5552-3691, running w10

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> i proceeded to open the laptop and clean the vent and the fan, which turned out to be just a little dirty

But was it really too hot?

In case of overheating, this is only part of the solution, it might required that you need to replace the solid thermal grease between the CPU and the heat sink.

*If and only if* you made sure there's no overheating, you need to look for power and driver issues.

A power issue can be pinpointed by downloading OCCT and then run the test under the Power Supply tab for a limited amount of time. I'm speaking of just a few minutes here, as this test is designed to draw power (and resulting temperatures) to of your system you don't want to decrease lifetime...

If it is a power issue, try without a battery as well as measure whether the power charger still provides the requirements as per its specifications. Consider buying a replacement battery and/or power charger in this case. It is worth noting that the voltage should be equal whereas the ampere should be the same or higher, DO NOT USE a power charger with lower ampere than what your laptop draws.

If it is not a power issue, consider to update all the drivers attempting to cancel out low-level software issues. If it is not the drivers, do a RAM test, HDD test and a reinstall test to look for broken hardware.

If it is a hardware issue, try to remove as much unnecessary hardware as possible. A lot of laptops allow you to remove the WLAN and BT modules, take out one (but not all) of the SODIMMs and/or try them in a different slot and so on...

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply. 
Did as you told me, with OCCT and tried power supply. Temperature merely reaches 60 and the laptop shutsdown. Tried it two times with the same results.
Should i proceed testing ? how should i interpretate this?

Thanks again

Comment: @ataraxic: If the laptop shuts down it means the power supply or circuit does not provide enough stable power. Assume as example we have a laptop that requires 19V (volt) and 3A (ampere) input. Now as the laptop is a bit older and/or has an extra component or something, it might draw a bit more during a busy moment somewhere between 3A and 3.5A. As the power supply cannot provide this, the laptop does not receive this and therefore turns off due to a lack of power. If this is the case, it can be solved by buying a 19V 4A charger. My old laptop had a 6A and required 7A after 6years, extra SSD.

Comment: However, that's just one possibility. It might also be the case that the battery of your laptop is broken, causing unstable power while it is inserted. It may very well be that the power supply of the laptop itself is unstable. It even may be that one of the laptop's components draws power in an unstable way when under load. Typically to resolve this the power supply and battery charger is diagnosed. Diagnosing the power circuit of the laptop itself requires you to know a bit about electronics. If all else fails, you can however test the laptop removing some of it's non-vital components...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tom.
Forgot to mention that during this shutdown issues, laptop battery has always been out, so it  happens when plugged in.

I think you may be right and that it could be because of an unstable energy source or defective component. i´ll try with a new charger if possible.

Thanks again for your guidance 
.